# В чем ошибка в чек листе?

Tags: тестирование

Прохожу обучение по программе QA, нам было поручено разработать чек лист для тестирования сайта https://vn-russian.ru/
В ходе проверки мне объяснили что мой чек лист концептуально неправильный, однако я сделал его в полном соответствии с примером который я нашел в сети интернет
Кто-нибудь - объясните, что не так с моим чек листом? если возможно скиньте пример хорошего чек листа для тестирования [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что в ожидаемый результат писать? если проверка это ссылка. Писать "есть"?)

Comment: Пройдите бесплатный курс от яндекса по тестированию. ЗАймет не много времени, там расскажут, что такое хороший чек лист. У вас нет предусловий кейса(Например для "регистрация пользователя" - должно быть что то вида - пользователь не зарегистрирован). Ожидаемый результат так же должен быть прописан четко и ясно. Вот например кейс с пользователь авторизирован и пользователь не авторизирован как тестировать то? )) Одно из этого противоречит другому

Comment: @SwaD - дайте пожалуйста линк

Comment: Вбейте в поисковик - **яндекс практикум** и там смотрите курсы по тестированию